# Disabling horizontal scroll in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have implemented a ViewPager to swipe between fragments. The problem is that I want to disable the pagination until a certain condition would be satisfied. The code I show you below works nearly fine, but it disallows the vertical scrolling in the layout of the fragment, and I only want to disable the horizontal scroll, I mean, the transition between fragments.

I have a layout which contains a custom ViewPager as follows:

**layout_pager**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <mypackage.CustomViewPager android:id="@+id/viewpager" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and another layout to define the content of the Fragment which implements a ScrollView:

**layout_fragment**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <LinearLayout>
        <!-- Some TextViews, Images, Buttons, etc -->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The activity just assign the Adapter

**MyActivity**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.layout_pager);
        CustomViewPager viewPager = (CusotmViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

The CustomViewPager has a flag to indicate if it is allowed the pagination

**CustomViewPager**

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean enabled;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        enabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return enabled ? super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev) : false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return enabled ? super.onTouchEvent(event) : false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

Finally, the fragment intercepts touch events to check if the condition is satisfied in order to enable the pagintaion.

**MyFragment**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public MyFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment, container, false);
        final MyActivity myActivity = (MyActivity) getActivity();

        rootView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    View customViewPagerRoot = myActivity.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                    CustomViewPager viewPager = (CustomViewPager) customViewPagerRoot.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                    if (condition to allow the pagination) {
                        viewPager.setPagingEnabled(true);
                    } else {
                        viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I hope I have explained the problem properly, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the swipe between fragment

```
viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Hope this information helps you

Comment: Your solution fixes the problem of the vertical scrolling, but now despite of disallowing swipe between fragments, the screen moves little by little towards the next fragment